# Is there an autocmd-event that works on unmodified buffer with :x, but not :q

Tags: vim, autocmd

I want to autorun formatter when saving a file. Using `BufWritePre` doesn't work when quitting with `:x` (or `ZZ`), if the file hasn't yet been modified. `ExitPre` or `QuitPre` don't work either.

Comment: I do not think there is any autocmd for your special use case. Why do not just use `:wq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's beacuse `:x` nor `ZZ` saves buffer when it's not modified.
From [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#ZZ):

```
:x          Like ":wq", but write only when changes have been
            made.
```

If you would like to have it working on `:x/ZZ` you can map it to `:wq` which always saves buffer or use `BufWinLeave`